# Saving in NSDocumentDirectory 

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Having weird problem with my `NSDocumenDirectory` saving.
Here is a sneak preview:
First I pick images ( in my `imagePickerViewController`):

[image]

in my `PreviewController`:

[image]

So at first try, it was okay.

Then I revisit the `imagePickerViewController` to add another image:

[image]

in my `PreviewController`:

[image]

This is where the problem occurs. At the image above, it recopies the last image from the old preview (like a duplicate). I dunno what Im doing wrong in my codes. But Im saving it when a file exist. Kindly see:

```
for (int i = 0; i < info.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [info objectAtIndex:i]);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstSlotImages%d.png", i]];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]) {

            NSLog(@"file doesnt exist");

        } else {
            ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[info objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
            //----resize the images
            image = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:image toSize:CGSizeMake(256,256*image.size.height/image.size.width)];

            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];

            NSLog(@"saving at:%@",savedImagePath);
        }
}
```

What I need is to just reAdd AGAIN the same image with the new one.
Same as, like the last preview.

Comment: Please reattach images. We are not able to see those.

Comment: I readd them 4 times already. I dunno what the problem is.

Comment: Did the result of the 3 NSLog statements agree with the sequence of events?

Comment: Yes they are. Is there something wrong. Ireally dont know

Answer (score 1):

The four images are passed in the sequence that they show in the preview, so in the first example the orange cat is third, and in the second example, the orange cat is fourth.  The new image isn't saving because it is third, and you already have a file named "firstSlotImages2.png". If you re-save each image without checking if the file exists, you should get the result you are looking for.

There's a key in the media info:  `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` which returns an NSURL, convert it to a string and get the the `lastPathComponent`.  Use this as the file name to save to the directory you are saving it to.  You can then save the reference to these images by saving this same file name either in an NSMutableArray, or an NSMutableDictionary

Comment: Yes, you are right. but how to trigger that when the image you selected is already save in the nsdocumentdirectory it wont be save anymore?

Comment: @Kobe.o4 you can save it via it's fileURL last path component, which is unique to each photo